# laravel videos/files upload to aws s3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, file-upload, dropzone.js

im trying to upload files/images/videos to aws s3 using laravel.

on the local the upload works just fine, but when i try to upload the file on live aws server i am getting error.

i have tried both `putFileAs` and `put` method to upload videos on live aws s3 server. but still it fails.

upon checking logs for using `put` method i get this.

`[2018-04-20 17:35:25] production.ERROR: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen(): Filename cannot be empty at /var/app/current/app/Http/Controllers/Offer/LibraryController.php:149)`

i have been banging my head round and round on this since yesterday.
couldn't see why it is not getting the file name. i am giving full path.

this is my code.

i have tried both ways

using `put` method

```
$path = Storage::disk($disk)->put($storagePath.'/'.$FileNameForUpload, fopen($validatedData['file'], 'r+'), 'public');
```

using the `putFileAs` Method

```
$path = Storage::disk($disk)->putFileAs(
                    $storagePath, $validatedData['file'], $FileNameForUpload
                );
```

---

EDIT:

Only Videos gives the issue, but images and text files are uploading fine?

Comment: are file permissions okay??

Comment: $validatedData['file']; maybe causing the mess. may be its empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $destinationPath= 'Path of folder where you want to store file on S3 server with filename';

 Storage::disk($disk)->put($destinationPath, file_get_contents('filename with path'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Max file upload size was 2M :(

This is why other documents were uploading fine but video was like 2.7MB so it was giving error, however i am not sure why this laravel was not giving file limit error instead it was giving file name can not be empty?

Thou that issue has been fixed, updated the ini file for my php version 7 on aws.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, and I have fixed it.

1. Find the "php.ini" file (/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini) and open it by root (sudo)
2. Change `post_max_size=50M` and `upload_max_filesize=50M` (in your case just need to change upload_max_filesize).